# Soundcard and headset - microphone picks up low to no sound

Tags: usb, audio, sound-card, microphone

I have headset connected with two 3.5 mm jacks to my computer. I use my microphone mostly for communication via TeamSpeak. Unfortunately, in the last time, the other side hears sound which goes slowly to missing (it goes from normal level to no sound), or noise. I have tried more microphones but these problems are always the same. So I think that the problem will be in my sound card.

I hear about headset which has own built-in sound card - USB headsets - (Creative HS-720 or any other). I'm not expert in this way so I want to ask you if I buy this headset, will be my problems solved?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Before buying a new sound card or an external one, have you tried updating your drivers?

Comment: I thought in case problems relating to a drive I could realize problems before. But I didn't have any problems... But thanks for recommendation - I'm going to try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It indeed sounds like a defective sound card. I would try getting a cheap USB sound card [like this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001MSS6CS) or [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0027EMHM6) (image below - I bought this one for my laptop, when its sound card started not working properly):
[image]

You can still use your existing headset/speaker and mic with a USB sound card. So this may save you money, rather than testing with a USB headset with sound card.